# Arch Linux doesn't connect to hidden network after iwctl command

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

```
station wlan1 connect-hidden "123"
```

After using this command on (arch bootable USB  of last release )
output is

```
object not found
```

123 is real ssid of my hidden network
This could be happen because it is only numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Though I may not have the perfect answer here (n00b moment), have you tried connecting to the network through `iwd` instead issues with the `iwctl` command? Is `journalctl` running? Without more information about what may actually be going on in the background, it becomes very difficult to answer this question...